# Searching for an item within a list in a column and saving that item to a new column

Tags: python, string, pandas, list, search

I am very new to Python and need help!

I want to search a column of a data frame for an item in a list and if found, store that item in a new column.  My the location column is messy and am trying to extract a state abbreviation if there is one.

So far I have been able to find the columns where the search terms are found (I’m not sure if this is 100% correct), how would I take the search term that was found and store it in a new column?

```
state_search=('CO', 'CA', 'WI', 'VA', 'NY', 'PA', 'MA', 'TX',)

pattern = '|'.join(state_search) 

state_jobs_df=jobs_data_df.loc[jobs_data_df['location'].str.contains(pattern), :]
```

I want to take the state that was found and store that in a new 'state' column.  Thanks for any help.

[image]

---

```
print (jobs_data_df)
                                            location
0                                  Madison, WI 53702
1  Senior Training Leader located in Raynham, MA ...
2                                           Dixon CA
3                   Camphill, PA Weekends and nights
4           Charlottesville, VA Some travel required
5                                        Houston, TX
6                                   Denver, CO 80215
7  Respiratory Therapy Primary Location : TX- Som...
```

Comment: Since you're doing a regex search, I'd suppose to add `\b` around state names, so that some `SKY Hotel, NH` won't match Kentucky.

Comment: @9000 - yes, word boundaries - in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with word boundaries and filter non missing rows by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) or [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in state_search)
jobs_data_df['state'] = jobs_data_df['location'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
jobs_data_df = jobs_data_df[jobs_data_df['state'].notna()]
```

Or:

```
jobs_data_df = jobs_data_df.dropna(subset=['state'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hack-y, but a simpler solution might take a form similar to:

```
for row in dataRows:
    for state in state_search:
        if state in row:
            #put state in correct column here
            break #should break just the inner loop; if that doesn't happen, delete this line
```

It's probably helpful to think about how the underlying program would have to approach the problem (checking each row for a string that matches one of your states, then doing something with it), and go at that directly. Unless you're dealing with a huge load of data, it may not be worth going crazy fancy with regular expressions or the like.